# How to map skeleton to shape in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, kinect

I am trying to write a Tetris game using Kinect. There are two game players. One of the game players will move the blocks and the other will define the shape of the blocks using body positions.

Now, the challenge I am facing is : How do I map the body position to a block?

For example I have this shape given below.

[image]

I want to identify it as  a 'T' shape block. How do i Do it?\

Here is what I thot:

I will store sample images of all the blocks (total 10) and compare the skeleton image from camera to these stored images and then display the block to which the camera has a match.

However, this is the toughest part. How do I find a match? Even if I have a T shaped sample image, what processing do I do with this skeleton so that It resembles a T shape before the comparison can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a gesture recognition library.  Such as:

- https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures
- http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/

You can define the gestures as a static held position -- for example, "Menu" in the Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures library.  When the particular gesture is recognized an event is fired and you can then act upon it, by showing the shape you desire.